# Use SSH in a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, ssh, raspberry-pi

Hi i am currently making my own software to control a robot with a Raspberry Pi. I was wondering if it is possible to embed ssh into HTML code so when the user types in the Pi's IP address it then connects through to the pi via ssh.

Then what i would like to do is send commands through the ssh when they click a button. E.G. Backwards.

This then means i can control the GPIO pins from the raspberry pi through python code if i can get the data through.

I have wrote some of the control code as presented below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #commands{
            text-align: center;
            color: FF8300;
            font-size: 100px;
        }
        .controllbox{
            width: 610px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #arrowUp{
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
        }
        #arrowRight{
            text-align: right;
            position: static;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        #arrowDown{
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
        }
        #arrowLeft{
            text-align: left;
            position: static;
            margin-top: -200px;

        }
        #stop{
            width: 120px; 
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: -65%;
            margin-left: 34%;
            text-align: center;
            position: static;


        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="commands">Controll Me!!</h1>
    <div class="controllBox">
        <div id="arrowUp"><img src="arrowUp.jpg" class="controll" id="button1"></div>
        <div id="arrowRight"><img src="arrowRight.jpg" class="controll" id="button2"></div>
        <div id="arrowLeft"><img src="arrowLeft.jpg" class="controll" id="button3"></div>
        <div id="arrowDown"><img src="arrowDown.jpg" class="controll" id="button4"></div>
        <div id="stop"><img src="stop.jpg" class="controll" id="button5"></div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(){
           document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Foward' 
        }
        document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Right'
        }
        document.getElementById('button3').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Left'
        }
        document.getElementById('button4').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Backwards'
        }
        document.getElementById('button5').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Stop'
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

It will be greatly appreciated if you know how to do this or something similar as i am pulling my hair out, trying to find out how i do this.

Many thanks for your help
James.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Comment: https://github.com/aluzzardi/wssh

Comment: or even https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute SSH commands via HTML or Javascript (maybe JS, but more effort than it's worth).

What I would recommend because it's more secure and easier to manage is to submit a form to your webserver using PHP or Python or some other scripting language.

Your web server should then make a call to SSH to execute the command for you.

for example:

```
POST: example.com/forward.php?inst=backward&ip=1.2.3.4
```

and then PHP will format a command string to run SSH and then execute it with exec()

Comment: Thanks for that, i am a real novice at this and don't know PHP is there anything else you could help me with to mske this easier as this looks or at least sounds really difficult